# Como carregar um ng-controller através de ajax e injetar ele dentro do DOM

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, angularjs

Estou criando uma aplicação onde eu gostaria de fazer o carregamento dos meus módulos através de ajax. Essa aplicação utiliza do AngularJS para fazer o tratamento de cada módulo e estes são injetados no meu DOM usando Jquery, como no exemplo abaixo:

**EDIT** - (como solicitado por @EduardoBinoto)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="app">

        <section name="foo" ng-controller="fooCtrl">
            <button ng-click="bar()">my name is foo</button>
        </section>

        <script>
          angular.module('app',[])
            .controller('fooCtrl', ['$scope','$http', '$compile', function($scope, $http, $compile) {
                $scope.bar = function(){
                    //simulação de requisição $http que retornou um módulo
                    var ajaxResponse = 
                        '<section name="bar" ng-controller="barCtrl">'+
                            '<button ng-click="helloWorld()">hello world</button>'+
                        '</section>';
                    //inserção do conteúdo no body através do jQuery
                    $('body').append(ajaxResponse);
                    //compilação do novo controller
                    $compile($('body'),$scope);
              };
            }])
            .controller('barCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
                $scope.helloWorld = function(){ alert('Hello World!!!'); };
            }])
        ;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Preciso saber como posso fazer para que o angular enxergue este novo módulo após a inserção através do jquery.

**NOTA:** Procurei diversos conteúdos na internet e todos dizem que eu preciso executar um `$scope.$apply` ou um `$scope.$digest` mas não consegui entender em nenhum dos exemplos que achei como realmente usar isso nessa situação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Precisa compilar o `HTML` dinâmico antes de adicioná-lo ao DOM pelo JQuery
2. No momento de compilar precisa especificar o escopo no qual o HTML fornecido será compilado pois $compile retorna uma função que espera o contexto

Desta forma a solução do problema é a seguinte:

```
var ajaxResponse = '<section name="bar" ng-controller="barCtrl">'+
                        '<button ng-click="helloWorld()">hello world</button>'+
                    '</section>';

//COMPILE ANTES DE COLOCAR NO DOM Fornecendo o escopo                  
var compiled = $compile(ajaxResponse)($scope);

$('body').append(compiled);
```

Segue o plunker: [AQUI](http://plnkr.co/edit/03r1qVKk71B8Cewp03np)

Comment: VALEU MANIN! ERA TUDO QUE ME FALTAVA!!!

Answer (score 3):

Bom dia, para funcionar o que você esta querendo fazer, você deve usar `$compile()` do angular.

Exemplo:

```
var mainMod = angular.module('MainApp', []);
mainMod.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','$compile',


 var ajaxResponse =  '<section name="bar" ng-controller="barCtrl">'+
                        '<button ng-click="helloWorld()">hello world</button>'+
                     '</section>';

 //inserção do conteúdo no body através do jQuery
 $('body').append(ajaxResponse);

 //$compile
 $scope.compile = $compile(ajaxResponse)($scope);


    }
]);
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: cara tentei fazer da forma que você colocou mas não funcionou. mesmo eu chamando o `$compile` e executando ele no final da minha função o mesmo não fez com que o `ng-controller="barCtrl"` fosse lido e interpretado...

Comment: Voce pode postar seu código com completo para que eu possa visualizar, pois tenho certeza que $compile atenderá sua demanda. Att, Binotto

Comment: Pode ser trivial mas já que mesmo assim não funcionou verifica se o seu barCtrl está acessível no escopo da página, quero dizer, se ele está carregado na página.

Answer (score 1):

Se você utilizar somente o $().append() você estará apenas incluindo a string no html e não atualizando o DOM.

Existe uma diretiva que faz todos esse trabalho p/ nós desenvolvedores.

```
app.directive('dynamic', ['$compile', function($compile){
return{
  replace: true,
  link: function($scope, ele, attrs) {
      $scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function(html){
         if(!html)
            return;
         ele.html((type of(html) === 'string') ? html : html.data);
         $compile(ele.contents())($scope);
});
}
}
}]);
```

Depois de adicionar a diretiva para chamar basta você colocar.

```
<div data-dynamic="htmlDynamic" ></div>
```

no seu controller basta você implementar

```
$scope.htmlDynamic = "HTML AQUI";
```

Comment: eu tentei utilizar a diretiva acima como teste mas também não funcionou.

Comment: Pode me mandar como realizou a implementação ?